# Network time protocol (NTP)

Tags: linux, ntp

I have found a simulator called ntpdsim for NTP: http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/ntpdsim_new.html

I canot figure out on what OS I can use it. On the page there is no download content. So I thought it is integrated in the NTP package.

I have tried Ubuntu and Opensuse. On both I have installed NTP, but there is no program called ntpdsim.

How can I use this tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ntpdsim is indeed part of the ntp source tarball, however apparently not included in the distribution packages you cite.

When compiling from source, you need to run `./configure` with `--enable-simulator` to build/install it. That's at least what `./configure --help` says.

Comment: I have done ./configure --enable-simulator and then make, but getting an error: MOD_NANO undeclared

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem - it looks like this bug was fixed in the source tarball I'm using. Here's a link to the Gentoo bugzilla with a patch that might fix it: https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=270483

Comment: it seems to be this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntp/+bug/412242   I will try to use the bugfix

Answer (score 0):

Check `./configure --help` to see if there's a build option you need to enable.

Comment: I installed ntp via apt-get install. where should I execute your comand?

Comment: If you use `apt-get` you will have the options chosen by the user who built the Debian package.  Download the source and build it yourself.

Comment: ok, I download the sources and try to build it. I am doing it as usual: ./configure; make; make install; ?

Comment: That will get you the default options.  If ntpdsim is non-default, you'll need to give some options to `./configure`.  `./configure --help` will show you what options are available, with explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for : http://doc.ntp.org/4.2.2p1/ntpdsim.html

Comment: Oh right, I was assuming that @tobias didn't have any trouble finding a download for the main ntp package, he seemed to be asking if there was an additional separate download required for the simulator.